# What is the correct way to catch a write error in Realm using Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, macos, realm

We are importing quite a few items into our realm database client side on initialization. We are trying to figure out why it is crashing on some clients machines, but we are unsure of the correct way to "trap" this error to log it. I have read that write errors are not intended to be caught. Here is some simplified code

```
RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
[realm beginWriteTransaction];
for(NSDictionary* package in packages)
{
     CMPackage *realm_package = [my_type createOrUpdateInDefaultRealmWithValue:package];
}

[realm commitWriteTransaction];
```

The crash occurs when **createOrUpdateInDefaultRealmWithValue** is called, but only on some clients. We think it could just be an old file sticking around between updates, but we can't figure it out as we can't trap it. Is it safe to put a try/catch around the center statement? Is it safe to commit a write transaction when one of the writes was an error? Is there a good solution to this issue?

**EDIT:**

I should also note that we want to do it all in one transaction and be able to continue on with the transaction after one write failure as the speed is negatively affected if writes are done in separate transitions.

Comment: What error you get and what does `createOrUpdateInDefaultRealmWithValue` method do?

Comment: @Dmitry - The method is a realm method: realm.io/docs/objc/latest/api/Classes/RLMObject.html The exact exception is unknown as we cannot re-create it.

Comment: One quick observation, it's probably not a good idea to create a variable inside the for loop called `package`, when you're bringing in an `NSDictionary` variable named `package` as well. You can catch write errors with `commitWriteTransaction:(NSError *)error`, but if `createOrUpdateInDefaultRealmWithValue` is throwing an exception, you'll need to come up with a way to capture the exception message. It might be worth doing some checking on `package` to verify its information is valid before trying to add it to Realm.

Comment: @TiM - Nice catch with the same variable names (its corrected above). That was just a mistake translating it for posting. I had seen the transaction error handling, but this would abort the whole loop on error I would assume. The actual loop in our code is a bit more complex than posted so validation is a bit more involved. It loops through a lot of different realm object types via introspection which would make checking objects a pain. Not saying its impossible, but if there is a way to gracefully catch a single write exception without aborting the transaction, it would be very helpful.

Comment: Ah, sorry @David, I'v read it wrong. `createOrUpdateInDefaultRealmWithValue` doesn't throw exceptions, you get an assertion failure if something went wrong as it's a program error. You can throw and catch any application errors inside a write transaction, but make sure to validate an object before adding it to Realm.

Comment: @Dmitry - So I assume there is no way to ask Realm to validate a dictionary before insertion then? As I mentioned above, this code is dynamically choosing a class that inherited RLMObject, and then dynamically feeding in data. It would be great if there was a way to ask the RLMObject if it was going to be valid using its internal validator.

Comment: @David no, there is no "validation" mechanism you can use. Realm only throws exceptions for incorrect usage of the library and you should never catch them, because doing so is generally not safe with ARC Objective-C code. That's why `commitWriteTransaction:(NSError *)error` exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the above conversation with Realm engineers, it would appear the testing and validating individual inserts on a transaction is not supported and errors can only be caught on a per-transaction basis. I would assume, as this is a transaction, that this would then roll back all other inserts if an exception occurs.